# Sing up via social networks in android app

Tags: android, database, facebook, authentication, google-plus

Some apps have such possibility as ***sing up*** via google+ or facebook etc.

But what does this possibility mean? What should developer do? Should developer send token to the remote db? But it migh be insecure. And the token might be expired after some time.

How can we determine particular user in the future? What is the best practices for such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the user is signing up to use your application by logging in to the social network, and then authorizing your application to access the basic information like name, email address, picture, etc. from it. This typically is a low friction process for the users anyway, because if they choose to sign up using a social network, chances are they are already logged in to it, and also they have already filled their information there.

The process consists of three steps:

- Your application redirects the user to login to the social network. This is done through the SDK/API the social network offers. Here's how to [login with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1)
- Your application requests the user ID from the social network, then checks if it has an application record with the same social network user ID. If it has one, this is an existing user who is just logging in to your app. If it doesn't have, it's a new user registering for your application. Here's how to [fetch the user data from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph/).
- In the case of a new user, your application creates new user record, associates it with the social network user ID, and optionally requests additional user information from the social network it needs to store in the new record. For how to do it with Facebook, look at the link from step 2.

Note that this process is pretty much the same when a new user registers with your application using a social network, or an existing user is logging in to your application using a social network. The main difference is that for existing users you stop at step 2, for new users you go through step three.

There's a scenario where you fetch the step 3 information from the social network even for existing users if you want to refresh your record, mostly for profile pictures that people change often. Keep in mind though, that in general keeping copy of the user information is frowned upon by both the social networks, and the users, so you probably want to keep locally only the minimum information you need and always fetch anything else you need from the social network.